# How to find location of Smarty custom function

Tags: php, smarty

I'm not so familiar with Smarty. In the code I'm exploring, I have found such construction:

```
<a href="{url a.category=$bcm_content.category_url a.subcategory=$bcm_content.subcategory_url a.nice_url=$bcm_content.series.content_nice_url item}?nord#header" title="...">...</a>
```

Can't understand, how does that `url` construction work. Looks like it is some custom method (or whatever it's called) in our project. But the project is quite large and I can't find it's definition just by word `url`.

Where to look for? What can it be?

Comment: If you don't know where the custom plugins stored, you can search for files called `function.url.php` or you could search in all php files for `function smarty_function_url`. If you have access to the smarty instance, you could also print all  registered plugin directories with `var_dump($smarty->getPluginsDir());`

Answer (score 0):

url - is a Smarty custom plugin, which you can find in smartys' plugin folder. a.category, a.subcategory, a.nice_url: are params that passed to the url.

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
{url ...}
```

`url` is the custom [Smarty Function](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.functions.tpl). You can find it in Smarty plug-in directory or in a file that keeps all functions (if there is one) for your project.

In case you want to find *the ends*, just search through your whole web-site directory for the following content:

```
smarty_function_url
```

It must be found anyway, because it's the only way you can register custom *Smarty function*.

#### EDIT 1:

As correctly stated by [sofl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1372119/sofl), if the plug-in is registered dynamically using [`registerPlugin`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl) method:

```
$smarty->registerPlugin("function","url", ...)
```

then you would have to search for the following instead:

```
registerPlugin("function","url"
```

or

```
registerPlugin(" function ", " url "
```

If it still doesn't work just try searching for `->registerPlugin`, I think there is no other options left after all and you will find it!

Comment: If the plugin is registered via `registerPlugin`, it is possible you will not find it with term `smarty_function_url`

Comment: @sofl Thanks for the missing tip, updated my answer!